# Adding an item to right-click menu on window

Tags: unity

I have some problems with my firefox consuming too much resources on my system when I have a lot of tabs open.

Nocsript addon and such helps somewhat, so most of the time that is ok.

But, when I am about to start a CPU-intensive operation it does get in the way, so knowing I will not need it for the time being, I am using a little snippet that does a 
"kill - STOP" on firefox, and toggle it back on with "kill -CONT"
when I need it again.

This works nicely, I was wondering, though, whether there is a simple way to integrate this into the UI.

I was thinking of the "right-click on window" menu, which normally offers
maximize/minimize and move to workspaces.

Is this possible, and if so, advisable?

Pointing me to the necessary docs or right places would be all I need,
of course a more detailed answer would be great, I have only found
answers on the Nautilus context menu so far.

Comment: meh. Looked on wrong site, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265984/how-to-customize-window-menu-linux-ubuntu seems to cover this already. Conclusion: possible, yes. Advisable: no, building metacity from source for this is way too much effort for too little gain.

Comment: If you want to integrate that into window's right click menu, then yes, this might be rather tedious, although you can try to add this option onto .desktop file, which allows to do such actions upon click on the icon in the sidebar. What do you think about it?

Comment: that sounds like a pretty good idea, actually. Opening sidebar and clicking is not quite what I had in mind, but easy enough that it would still beat opening a terminal or switching and typing. Any hint how to go about it?

Comment: found firefox.desktop in /usr/share/applications and added the option. Nice idea, Paulius, if you would like to answer, I will accept it as a solution.

Comment: I have now added instead an item to the launcher by creating a .desktop file, since my changes will otherwise likely be overwritten by updates. Also, this is easier to click, but it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier to customize solution would be using a desktop file instance which can be accessed via unity's sidebar's popup (right-click) menu.

This can be done via [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand) on firefox's *.desktop* file or even by creating your own.